# Создание кнопок внутри объекта ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, aide

Пробую создать список, который включает в себя кнопки/кнопку. Но каждый раз получается небольшой отпуск.

**Должно выглядеть:**

[image: Ожидание]

**Выглядит на самом деле:**

[image: Реальность]

**Разметка:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Код Активити:**

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Choose> products = new ArrayList();

    ListView ChooseList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.games);

        if(products.size()==0){
            products.add(new Choose("", ""));
            products.add(new Choose("", ""));
            products.add(new Choose("", ""));
            products.add(new Choose("", ""));
            products.add(new Choose("", ""));
        }
        ChooseList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Choose);
        ChooseAdapter adapter = new ChooseAdapter(this, R.layout.game, products);
        ChooseList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**Класс объекта:**

```
import android.widget.*;

public class Choose
{
    private String Text_1, Text_2;
    TextView names;
    public String choose_1="Some Text",choose_2="Some Text";

    Choose(String Text_1, String Text_2){
        this.Text_1 = choose_1;
        this.Text_2 = choose_2;
    }
    public  String Text_1Set(){
        return Text_1;
    }
    public  String Text_2Set(){
        return Text_2;
    }
}
```

**Адаптер:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class ChooseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Choose> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int layout;
    private ArrayList<Choose> ChooseList;

    ChooseAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Choose> products) {
        super(context, resource, products);
        this.ChooseList = products;
        this.layout = resource;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final Choose product = ChooseList.get(position);

        viewHolder.first_t.setText(product.Text_1Set());
        viewHolder.second_t.setText(product.Text_2Set());

        viewHolder.first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    viewHolder.first_t.setText("-");
                }
            });
        viewHolder.second.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    viewHolder.second_t.setText("+");
                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        final Button first, second;
        final TextView first_t, second_t;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            first = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Text1);
            second = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Text2);
            first_t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Text1);
            second_t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Text2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Вопрос**: как можно реализовать, чтобы были две(одна) кнопки(-а), которые будут растянуты по всей поверхности?

Comment: в этом коде нет проблем, которые могли бы привести к результату на втором скриншоте. Либо проблема в другом месте, либо код в вопросе не соответствует коду в проекте, либо это глюк какой то, например при сборке не учитываеются сделанные изменения. Зато у вас есть проблема, что изменения в айтемах при кликах нигде не сохраняются, при скроллинге эти изменения будут потеряны. Для 5 элементов в списке это неважно, но если список будет достаточно длинным, чтобы скроллится, то проблему нужно будет решать.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо!) А каким образом сохранять можно, просто я думаю сделать довольно большой список?

Comment: В вашем случае наверное будет самое простое сделать в модели сеттер и записывать туда новое значение вместе с изменением содержимого виджета при обработке клика